# I can't print my version of TensorFlow: print(tf.__version__)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I just ran this in Spyder:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

I'm getting this error message.

```
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-77a1a5d49dcd>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Error in callback <bound method AutoreloadMagics.post_execute_hook of <autoreload.AutoreloadMagics object at 0x000001C5AB02A2C8>> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 538, in post_execute_hook
    _, pymtime = self._reloader.filename_and_mtime(sys.modules[modname])

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 184, in filename_and_mtime
    if not hasattr(module, '__file__') or module.__file__ is None:

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have been battling some weird issues in TensorFlow.  I uninstalled and re-install TF a couple times already.  Still encountering weird issues, which I don't totally understand. How can I get this resolved once and for all?

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow have you installed GPU or CPU?

Comment: When I run a diagnostic, I see this: tensorboard==2.1.1 & 
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.6.0.post3 & 
tensorflow==2.1.0 & 
tensorflow-datasets==2.0.0 & 
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0 & 
tensorflow-hub==0.8.0 & 
tensorflow-metadata==0.21.1 &

Comment: what command did you use to install TensorFlow "pip install tensorflow" or "pip install tensorflow-gpu"

Comment: I used "pip install tensorflow"

Comment: I actually got this working! I had to 'conda update conda' at the command prompt and 'spyder --reset' also at the command prompt. I had to get the latest C++ distributable as well. Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: okay, did you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following steps work for you. I solved it for the same issue.

First, install a `Visual C++` Redistributable Package.

Second, upgrade TensorFlow as follows.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```